# definite integral negative variable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Man, it's been so long since I did this. I am trying to do this:

*NB: limits are $-\pi$ and 0, but I can't get the minus in the limits. If anybody knows how do to that please let me know, the $\pi$ symbol jumps into the integrand when I type minus before it...*

$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int^0_{-\pi} -t dt
$$

I move the minus out of the integral:
$$
-\frac{1}{\pi}\int^0_{-\pi} t dt
$$

I do the integration:

$$
-\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \left[\frac{t^2}{2}\right]^0_{-\pi}
$$

I insert the limits, the final limit is zero, so the second term is removed:

$$
-\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{(-\pi)^2}{2}
$$

$$
-\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{2}
$$

$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

But this is incorrect. It should be:

$$
+\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

So my question is: Do I have to change the signing when I do definite integrals on the left side of the y axis?

Comment: @scott thanks, curly brackets. Got it!

Comment: No problem DrOnline!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you evaluate $$-\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\dfrac{t^2}{2}\right)\Big|_{-\pi}^0$$

Which is $$-\frac 1{\pi}\left[\left(\dfrac{0^2}{2}\right) - \left(\dfrac{(-\pi)^2}{2}\right)\right] = -\frac 1{\pi}\left[0 - \left(\dfrac{(-\pi)^2}{2}\right)\right] -\frac 1{\pi}\cdot -\frac{\pi^2}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Wow, I was doing F(a)-F(b) when it should be like you do F(b)-F(a)

Comment: Yes, that's all it was...just a simple mix-up in the order of evaluating at your bounds. Otherwise, you were "spot on"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't vote up until I have 15 rep, so I'm gonna vote you up when I get to that, bookmarking for now. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, DrOnline!

Comment: Done! I was waiting for the timer to go out, one has to wait like 5 minutes after receiving the answer to accept it :D

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback and I know the thumbs ups is not as nice at that beautiful green check, but +1!

Comment: thanks, Amzoti...it's always nice to show an OP that there's little wrong with their real work...just some simple mis-step!